# ColdFusion 9 and Dropzone.js - send form elements on remove link

Tags: coldfusion, dropzone.js, coldfusion-9

I have multiple dropzones in my ColdFusion code as such:

```
<cfform name='UploadFiles' action="uploadfiles.cfm" class="dropzone">
   <input type="hidden" name="doctype" value="<cfoutput>#REQUIREMENT_CODE_KEY#</cfoutput>">
</cfform>
```

Currently when a file is uploaded, I put the original filename into my database and also rename the file and put that into the database. When the document is renamed, it uses the hidden value passed from the form (doctype).

Lets say someone uploaded the same file twice. This would put in the database two different renamed filenames (filename in image below), but it would have the same original filenames (orig_filename in image below). The only difference between the two records would be the value of the hidden element sent with the upload (doctype). ie:
[image]

The issue is that if they were to try to remove one of the files, both would be removed, because the only information dropzone has is the original filename. How can I get ColdFusion to pass the new filename back to the dropzone.js so that it can use that value to know exactly which line to delete?

Comment: Can't you add another hidden field to the form with some unique identifier? I guess that would require adding another column to the database to store it. In my opinion all of your database tables should already have unique identifiers to avoid this situation.

Comment: Uploading two files with the same name does not necessarily mean they are the same file.  I suggest presenting information to the user so he or she can decide exactly what file to delete.

Comment: @Miguel-F I am okay with adding another fild to the database. The issue is that this hidden fields are passed when the file is uploaded. But after  uploaded, there is a remove file link that does not have the hidden field info. So the same would be the case with any unique id created.

Comment: @DanBracuk There is a separate dropzone field for each document type. So n essence, I am giving the user the option, by allowing them to remove the file that was uploaded for that particular document type.

Comment: @LaurenRobinson the idea is if you store some unique identifier in the database then you also retrieve that identifier when you retrieve the other file information for the remove link. The identifier can be added as a hidden field with that form. Maybe I'm not understanding your process entirely. Perhaps add some more detail to your question.